# Flex 4 VideoPlayer hide full screen button

Tags: button, video, flex4, fullscreen, video-player

How can I hide the VideoPlayer's fullscreen button please and make all the other components "snap" to full width instead of having a gap there?

Answer (score 1):

You edit the skin. :)